# Calculating prime numbers in Scala: how does this code work?

Tags: scala, stream, primes

So I've spent hours trying to work out exactly how this code produces prime numbers.

```
lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter(i =>
   ps.takeWhile{j => j * j <= i}.forall{ k => i % k > 0});
```

I've used a number of printlns etc, but nothings making it clearer.

This is what I think the code does:

```
/**
 * [2,3] 
 * 
 * takeWhile 2*2 <= 3 
 * takeWhile 2*2 <= 4 found match
 *      (4 % [2,3] > 1) return false.
 * takeWhile 2*2 <= 5 found match
 *      (5 % [2,3] > 1) return true 
 *          Add 5 to the list
 * takeWhile 2*2 <= 6 found match
 *      (6 % [2,3,5] > 1) return false
 * takeWhile 2*2 <= 7
 *      (7 % [2,3,5] > 1) return true
 *          Add 7 to the list
 */
```

But If I change `j*j` in the list to be 2*2 which I *assumed* would work exactly the same, it causes a stackoverflow error.

I'm obviously missing something fundamental here, and could really use someone explaining this to me like I was a five year old.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why use "lazy"?  Initializing the Stream doesn't take much time or memory, and it works fine without `ps` being lazy, right?

Comment: @AmigoNico mmlac brought this to my attention in a comment on my answer -- `lazy` may actually be necessary since the `val` has a recursive definition. Curiously, in my own testing in Scala 2.10.4, `lazy` was _not_ required at the REPL but was required in ordinary code -- presumably a REPL bug.

Comment: Ah, of course it does.  I should have looked more closely.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not sure that seeking a procedural/imperative explanation is the best way to gain understanding here. Streams come from functional programming and they're best understood from that perspective. The key aspects of the definition you've given are:

1. It's *lazy*. Other than the first element in the stream, nothing is computed until you ask for it. If you never ask for the 5th prime, it will never be computed.
2. It's *recursive*. The list of prime numbers is defined in terms of itself.
3. It's *infinite*. Streams have the interesting property (because they're lazy) that they can represent a sequence with an infinite number of elements. `Stream.from(3)` is an example of this: it represents the list [3, 4, 5, ...].

Let's see if we can understand why your definition computes the sequence of prime numbers.

The definition starts out with `2 #:: ...`. This just says that the first number in the sequence is 2 - simple enough so far.

The next part defines the rest of the prime numbers. We can start with all the counting numbers starting at 3 (`Stream.from(3)`), but we obviously need to filter a bunch of these numbers out (i.e., all the composites). So let's consider each number `i`. If `i` is not a multiple of a lesser prime number, then `i` is prime. That is, `i` is prime if, for all primes `k` less than `i`,  `i % k > 0`. In Scala, we could express this as

```
nums.filter(i => ps.takeWhile(k => k < i).forall(k => i % k > 0))
```

However, it isn't actually necessary to check all lesser prime numbers -- we really only need to check the prime numbers whose square is less than or equal to `i` (this is a fact from number theory`*`). So we could instead write

```
nums.filter(i => ps.takeWhile(k => k * k <= i).forall(k => i % k > 0))
```

So we've derived your definition.

Now, if you happened to try the first definition (with `k < i`), you would have found that it didn't work. Why not? It has to do with the fact that this is a recursive definition.

Suppose we're trying to decide what comes after 2 in the sequence. The definition tells us to first determine whether 3 belongs. To do so, we consider the list of primes up to the first one greater than or equal to 3 (`takeWhile(k => k < i)`). The first prime is 2, which is less than 3 -- so far so good. But we don't yet know the second prime, so we need to compute it. Fine, so we need to first see whether 3 belongs ... BOOM!

`*` *It's pretty easy to see that if a number `n` is composite then the square of one of its factors must be less than or equal to `n`. If `n` is composite, then by definition `n == a * b`, where `1 < a <= b < n` (we can guarantee `a <= b` just by labeling the two factors appropriately). From `a <= b` it follows that `a^2 <= a * b`, so it follows that `a^2 <= n`.*

Comment: Thank you Aaron. Very much appreciated. I did in fact try the k < i ( as well as countless other scenarios trying to work this out) I now understand why it went BOOM! Thanks again.

Comment: Will break in current scalac with "forward reference extends over definition of value ps" error. Tested 2.11.4, 2.10.4 and 2.9.0

Comment: @mmlac What breaks? The OP's original code? Only in 2.11?

Comment: @AaronNovstrup If I understand your solution correctly, this should work. Error inline.

https://gist.github.com/mmlac/fb5e850b17ebdd2d94bc

Comment: @mmlac No, I don't think an ordinary `val` can have a recursive definition. It may have to be `lazy`.

Answer (score 3):

Your explanations are mostly correct, you made only two mistakes:

`takeWhile` doesn't include the last checked element:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).takeWhile(_<2)
res1: List[Int] = List(1)
```

You assume that `ps` always contains only a two and a three but because `Stream` is lazy it is possible to add new elements to it. In fact each time a new prime is found it is added to `ps` and in the next step `takeWhile` will consider this new added element. Here, it is important to remember that the tail of a `Stream` is computed only when it is needed, thus `takeWhile` can't see it before `forall` is evaluated to true.

Keep these two things in mind and you should came up with this:

```
ps = [2]
i = 3
  takeWhile
    2*2 <= 3 -> false
  forall on []
    -> true
ps = [2,3]
i = 4
  takeWhile
    2*2 <= 4 -> true
    3*3 <= 4 -> false
  forall on [2]
    4%2 > 0 -> false
ps = [2,3]
i = 5
  takeWhile
    2*2 <= 5 -> true
    3*3 <= 5 -> false
  forall on [2]
    5%2 > 0 -> true
ps = [2,3,5]
i = 6
...
```

While these steps describe the behavior of the code, it is not fully correct because not only adding elements to the `Stream` is lazy but every operation on it. This means that when you call `xs.takeWhile(f)` not all values until the point when `f` is false are computed at once - they are computed when `forall` wants to see them (because it is the only function here that needs to look at all elements before it definitely can result to true, for false it can abort earlier). Here the computation order when laziness is considered everywhere (example only looking at 9):

```
ps = [2,3,5,7]
i = 9
  takeWhile on 2
    2*2 <= 9 -> true
  forall on 2
    9%2 > 0 -> true
  takeWhile on 3
    3*3 <= 9 -> true
  forall on 3
    9%3 > 0 -> false
ps = [2,3,5,7]
i = 10
...
```

Because `forall` is aborted when it evaluates to false, `takeWhile` doesn't calculate the remaining possible elements.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply to this. This is making a lot sense to me now, the clarification of how the lazy keyword works also really helped explain why I was getting the println outputs I was getting.

Comment: @AlanHollis: the lazy keyword is not needed in this case, the code also works without it. This is because `Stream` internally is already lazy. The keyword just makes the call to the reference lazy, not the data structure itself.

Answer (score 2):

That code is easier (for me, at least) to read with some variables renamed *suggestively*, as

```
lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter(i =>
   ps.takeWhile{p => p * p <= i}.forall{ p => i % p > 0});
```

This reads *left-to-right* quite naturally, as

> *primes* are *2*, and those numbers `i` from *3* up, that *all* of the *primes* `p` whose square does not exceed the `i`, do *not* divide `i` evenly (i.e. without some non-zero remainder).

In a true recursive fashion, to understand this definition as defining the ever increasing stream of primes, we *assume* that it *is* so, and from that assumption we see that no contradiction arises, i.e. the truth of the definition holds.

The only potential problem after that, is the timing of accessing the stream `ps` *as it is being defined*. As the first step, imagine we just have another stream of primes provided to us from somewhere, magically. Then, after seeing the truth of the definition, check that the timing of the access is okay, i.e. we never try to access the areas of `ps` before they are defined; that would make the definition stuck, *unproductive*.

I remember reading somewhere (don't recall where) something like the following -- a conversation between a student and a wizard,

- *student:* which numbers are prime?
- *wizard:* well, do you know what number is the first prime?
- *s:* yes, it's *2*.
- *w:* okay (quickly writes down *2* on a piece of paper). And what about the next one?
- *s:* well, next candidate is *3*. we need to check whether it is divided by any prime whose square does not exceed it, but *I don't yet know what the primes are!*
- *w:* don't worry, I'l give them to you. It's a magic I know; I'm a wizard after all.
- *s:* okay, so what is the first prime number?
- *w:* (glances over the piece of paper) *2*.
- *s:* great, so its square is already greater than 3... *HEY, you've cheated!* .....

---

Here's a pseudocode<sup>1</sup> translation of your code, read partially *right-to-left*, with some variables again renamed for clarity (using `p` for "prime"):

```
ps = 2 : filter (\i-> all (\p->rem i p > 0) (takeWhile (\p->p^2 <= i) ps)) [3..]
```

which is also

```
ps = 2 : [i | i <- [3..], and [rem i p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p->p^2 <= i) ps]]
```

which is a bit more visually apparent, using [list comprehensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension). `and` checks that all entries in a list of Booleans are `True` (read `|` as "for", `<-` as "drawn from", `,` as "such that" and `(\p-> ...)` as "*lambda* of `p`").

So you *see*, `ps` ***is a lazy list*** of 2, and then of numbers `i` drawn from a stream `[3,4,5,...]` such that for all `p` drawn from `ps` such that `p^2 <= i`, it is true that `i % p > 0`. Which is actually an *optimal* [trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) algorithm. :)

There's a subtlety here of course: the list `ps` is open-ended. We use it as it is being "fleshed-out" (that of course, because it is lazy). When `p`s are taken from `ps`, it could potentially be a case that we run past its end, in which case we'd have a non-terminating calculation on our hands (a "*black hole*"). It just so happens :) (and needs to ⁄ can be proved mathematically) that this is impossible with the above definition. So 2 is put into `ps` unconditionally, so there's something in it to begin with.

But if we try to "simplify",

```
bad = 2 : [i | i <- [3..], and [rem i p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p->p < i) bad]]
```

it stops working after producing just one number, 2: when considering 3 as the candidate, `takeWhile (\p->p < 3) bad` demands the next number in `bad` after 2, but there aren't yet any more numbers there. It "jumps ahead of itself".

This is "fixed" with

```
bad = 2 : [i | i <- [3..], and [rem i p > 0 | p <- [2..(i-1)] ]]
```

but that is a much much slower trial division algorithm, very far from the *optimal* one.

--

<sup>1</sup> ([Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#Quicksort_in_Haskell) actually, it's just easier for me that way :)  )

Comment: Thank you Will Ness, the psuedocode helped a lot. I think because the ordering of the all and the takeWhile funtions are left->right which makes it easier to read. The fixed version helped me understand where I was going wrong trying to achieve the same thing in a less complex manor! Thanks again, Alan

Comment: @AlanHollis glad that helped. :) wan't sure at all if it would. :) With 2 instead of `j` we get `ps = 2 : [i | i <- [3..], and [rem i p > 0 | p <- takeWhile (\p->4 <= i) ps]]` so for `i==3` it's `takeWhile (\p->False) ps == []` and 3 goes through OK (because `and [] == True`), but for `i==4` it is `takeWhile(p->True) ps` which never stops asking new numbers from `ps`.