# Understanding Streams

Tags: scala

There is one pattern that reappears again and again and I haven't been able to understand it completely, for example the below [code](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) to calculate `isPrime`

```
class S99Int(val start: Int) {
  import S99Int._
  def isPrime: Boolean =
    (start > 1) && (primes takeWhile ( _ <= Math.sqrt(start) ) forall ( start % _ != 0 ))
}

object S99Int {
  implicit def int2S99Int(i: Int): S99Int = new S99Int(i)
  val primes = Stream.cons(2, Stream.from(3, 2) filter { _.isPrime })
}
import S99Int._

24 isPrime        //returns false
```

What I dont understand is that: `primes` in the `filter` uses `isPrime`. But again the `def isPrime` uses the same `primes` to take elements. Isn't it like an infinite loop where one thing asks another and then that thing again to one-self. Though the code works perfect.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594227/calculating-prime-numbers-in-scala-how-does-this-code-work for a similar question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams in Scala are lazily evaluated. That means only the values up to the last value you actually need are calculated. What does this mean for your prime example:

`isPrime` does not use the whole `primes` stream, but only a portion of it:

```
(primes takeWhile ( _ <= Math.sqrt(start) )
```

It uses only the portion of it which is smaller than the square root of the number you want to test (and the next one, as you have to evaluate it to see it is too big). When now `primes` calls `isPrime` again for one of those smaller numbers, the required part of `primes` is even smaller. This goes on until you reach the initial 2.

Think of it as a mutually recursive functions:

- `isPrime` as is
- `primes` could be considered as `primesUpTo(n: Int)`

And then:

```
class S99Int(val start: Int) {
  import S99Int._
  def isPrime: Boolean =
    (start > 1) && (S99Int.primesUpTo(math.sqrt(start).toInt) forall ( start % _ != 0 ))
}

object S99Int {
  implicit def int2S99Int(i: Int): S99Int = new S99Int(i)
  def primesUpTo(n: Int): IndexedSeq[Int] = {
    if (n >= 2) 2 +: (3 to n) filter { _.isPrime }
    else IndexedSeq.empty
  }
}
```

The only thing the `Stream` achieves for you is to cache values from `primesUpTo(n: Int)` so that they are calculated only once and to make the expression `UpTo` more intuitive for a functional programmer.