# Scala stream to find primes in specific interval

Tags: scala, stream, functional-programming, primes

**Problem:**

I need to create a Scala program which uses Stream class and finds n-th prime number from interval [i, j] (whereas 1 <= i < j).

**More information:**

I am completely new in Scala but I've looked for various examples on how to find primes in Scala using Stream. None of them helped me to achieve my goal.

I can't seem to understand how to make stream a finite list in interval [i, j] and how to take n-th prime number from that interval.

**My code so far:**

```
def primeStream(args: Array[String], s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] =
        Stream.cons(s.head, primeStream(args,s.tail filter {_ % s.head != 0 }))

if (args(0).toInt < 1) {
        println("Entered parameter i does not meet requirements 1<=i<j (1<=" + args(0) + "<" + args(1) + ")")
        sys.exit(1)
} else if (args(1).toInt < args(0).toInt) {
        println("Entered parameter j does not meet requirements 1<=i<j (1<=" + args(0) + "<" + args(1) + ")")
        sys.exit(1)
}

val primes = primeStream(args,Stream.from(args(0).toInt)) // start from i element

primes take args(1).toInt foreach println //Take j elements
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**SOLUTION:**

```
def primeStream(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] =
        Stream.cons(s.head, primeStream(s.tail filter {_ % s.head != 0 }))

if (args(0).toInt < 1) {
        println("Entered parameter i does not meet requirements 1<=i<j (1<=" + args(0) + "<" + args(1) + ")")
        sys.exit(1)
} else if (args(1).toInt < args(0).toInt) {
        println("Entered parameter j does not meet requirements 1<=i<j (1<=" + args(0) + "<" + args(1) + ")")
        sys.exit(1)
} else if (args(0).toInt == 1) {
        println("1 is not a prime by definition!") 
        sys.exit(1)  // if args(0) is 1 then function hangs up - didn't come up with a better solution for this
}

val primes = primeStream(Stream.from(args(0).toInt)) // get primes starting from given parameter

println(primes.takeWhile( _ < args(1).toInt).take(args(2).toInt).last) // get n-th prime and print it out
```

Comment: Why does `primeStream` take the `args` parameter?

Comment: I run this script from console and pass 3 arguments into `args` array.

Comment: I just wanted to make you reason about the fact that, in your example, the parameter has no role in that one-line `primeStream` method: it is just passed along and along, thus completely useless.

Comment: Oh! You're right. I was trying hard to get it to working by _any_ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to have your stream generate values while a certain condition holds:

```
primes takeWhile(_ < j) take n foreach println
```

and, of course, you need to get the `primeStream` function right.

For the algorithmic part, you'd better search on stackoverflow:

- [Calculating prime numbers in Scala: how does this code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594227/calculating-prime-numbers-in-scala-how-does-this-code-work)

Comment: Thanks! This now gives me interval [i; j] from which I should take specific n-th element. How do I take this n-th element?

I assume, that I pass 3 arguments: i j k

Comment: You need to take the last element in the resulting stream, i.e., `primes takeWhile(_ < j) take n last`

Comment: Hmm, I feel a bit dumb now. Why last? For example, I have a list of primes in interval `[2; 13]` and I want to take 5-th (n-th) element which is 11 [2,3,5,7,**11**,13]. How do I check that 11 is 5-th element?

Comment: It is the `last` in what you get *after* you take `n` elements.

Comment: Nope, I can't get it to work. If I run it like this: `primes takeWhile( _ < args(1).toInt) take args(2).toInt last` then there is a warning stating _"there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details"_. If I leave it like this: `primes takeWhile( _ < args(1).toInt) take args(2).toInt last println` then it shows error _"Int does not take parameters"_. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: You can remove the warning just by avoiding the "operator syntax": `primes.takeWhile(_ < j).take(n).last`

Answer (score 1):

Is this a learning exercise, or do you need this in production? For the latter, I would suggest using spire.math.prime.stream from the [spire](https://github.com/non/spire) library. It is using a *Segmented Stream of Eratosthenes* implementation which is probably better than what you will come up with yourself in a short time. It also uses arbitrary precision integers, so it works for numbers larger than 2^64.

```
scala> import spire.math._
import spire.math._

scala> prime.stream.drop(10).take(10).toArray
res16: Array[spire.math.SafeLong] = Array(31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71)
```

Comment: Yes, it is a learning exercise. Thank you very much for your comment - it indeed looks easier and better but I will go with my solution.

Comment: I found a problem that if I change interval from `[2,..]` to something greater than 2, e.g. `[20,30]` and execute `scala prime.scala 20 30 2` it returns 21 but it should return 29 as it is second prime in this specific interval.

I tried to manipulate with `takeWhile` to achieve needed result but so far no luck. What should I change in my program in order to achieve that?

Can you please help?